# Repeated random samples for t-tests in R

Tags: r, matrix, random

I have data from two time periods (1999 and 2009).  The data is in two columns, one called "values" (4.960001, 4.847222, ... 3.639985, 3.849003) and one called "time" (1999, 1999, ..., 2009, 2009):

There are 75,049 values for each year. I'd like to randomly select 30 values (without replacement) from each year and conduct a paired T-test and then input the results into a matrix.  I'd like to run that procedure 1,000 times on the same dataset to get a distribution of T-test values.
Any ideas on how to do that would be much appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: sounds simple enough, how much does it pay?

Comment: to get you started, have a look at `sample`   You might also want to read the MASS book

Comment: hi, the reason some people is down voting your question is because it doesn't show any effort.

Comment: Oh.  I'm pretty new to R and have had a hard time on this.

Comment: @user2359494, I did not downvote this question.  However, you essentially are asking others to put in the effort _for you_.  You can be new to `R` but still use google, still try.  and then when you encounter a specific challenge, post what the question is.

Comment: Unlike Ricardo, I have concerns that this is statistical nonsense. How could randomly selected items get properly "paired" to each other? Just because you would be able to crank the handle on a paired-t-test function does not make the output meaningful.

Comment: @DWin, I wasn't clear.  The values refer to the same set of locations from both years.  So, I suppose I should list the values in columns by year such that each row corresponds to the same location across both years. In which case the randomly selected rows would not be independent from one another, but paired. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" ....two columns, one called "values" (4.960001, 4.847222, ... 3.639985, 3.849003) and one called "time" (1999, 1999, ..., 2009, 2009)" ..."75,049 values for each year."

Sounds like this could be done with:

```
 folded <- matrix(dfrm$values, ncol=2)
 replicate( 1000, { pick <- sample(1:75049, 30)
                    t.test(folded[pick, 1], folded[pick,2], paired=TRUE)$statistic
                   } )
```